# Looping through URLs with axios.get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I have an object full of museum names:

```js
const museumNamesForScraping = [
        "Boston Children's Museum (e-ticket)",
        "Boston Harbor Islands",
        "DCR - Mass Dept of Conservation and Recreation",
        "Hale Reservation",
        "Harvard Museums of Science and Culture",
        "ICA - Institute of Contemporary Art",
        "Isabella Stewart Gardner Museum (promo code)",
        "John F Kennedy Library and Museum",
        "Larz Anderson Auto Museum",
        "Mass Audubon Wildlife Sanctuary",
        "Museum of Fine Arts (e-voucher)",
        "Museum of Science (e-voucher)",
        "New England Aquarium (e-coupon)",
        "Old South Meeting House",
        "Old Sturbridge Village",
        "Peabody Essex Museum",
        "Trustees GO Pass",
        "USS Constitution Museum",
        "Zoo New England"
];
```

I am trying to add each of the above museum names onto a `URL` to scrape data from each page like such:

```js
    museumNamesForScraping.forEach((museumName) => {
            axios.get('https://www.eventkeeper.com/mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=' + museumName)
                .then(res => {
                        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
                        let title = $("title").text();
                        console.log(title);
                    }
                )
                .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                );
    });
```

Strangely, 3 or so out of the total list of museum names work each time I run the code with the rest erroring with the following details:

```
[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500] {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.eventkeeper.com/mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old South Meeting House',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'www.eventkeeper.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'www.eventkeeper.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 930031,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'GET /mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old%20South%20Meeting%20House HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
      'Host: www.eventkeeper.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 32,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old%20South%20Meeting%20House',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 500,
      statusMessage: 'Variable CHARLIE_SETTING_NONEXISTENT_VAR_TO_BREAK_APP_TO_STOP_LOOPING is undefined.',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://www.eventkeeper.com/mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old%20South%20Meeting%20House',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'www.eventkeeper.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://www.eventkeeper.com/mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old%20South%20Meeting%20House',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 500,
    statusText: 'Variable CHARLIE_SETTING_NONEXISTENT_VAR_TO_BREAK_APP_TO_STOP_LOOPING is undefined.',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'text/html',
      'retry-after': '5',
      server: 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      'server-error': 'true',
      'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
      date: 'Thu, 11 Aug 2022 03:05:07 GMT',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-length': '1208'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://www.eventkeeper.com/mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old South Meeting House',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old%20South%20Meeting%20House HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
        'Host: www.eventkeeper.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/mars/tkflex.cfm?curOrg=BOSTON&curNumDays=1&curKey1=Old%20South%20Meeting%20House',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'www.eventkeeper.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\r\n' +
      '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n' +
      '<head>\r\n' +
      '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>\r\n' +
      '<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>\r\n' +
      '<style type="text/css">\r\n' +
      '<!--\r\n' +
      'body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\n' +
      'fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\n' +
      'h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\n' +
      'h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\n' +
      'h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n' +
      '#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\n' +
      'background-color:#555555;}\r\n' +
      '#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n' +
      '.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n' +
      '-->\r\n' +
      '</style>\r\n' +
      '</head>\r\n' +
      '<body>\r\n' +
      '<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n' +
      '<div id="content">\r\n' +
      ' <div class="content-container"><fieldset>\r\n' +
      '  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>\r\n' +
      '  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>\r\n' +
      ' </fieldset></div>\r\n' +
      '</div>\r\n' +
      '</body>\r\n' +
      '</html>\r\n'
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to find much on the error's `statusText`:

```
statusText: 'Variable CHARLIE_SETTING_NONEXISTENT_VAR_TO_BREAK_APP_TO_STOP_LOOPING is undefined.',
```

Any help on how to troubleshoot this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `error code 500` is server's error, not your code. i think.

Comment: instead of using `forEach`, use normal `for` loop so then you can use keyword `continue` in `catch` function to skip over the errors in loop.

Comment: Care to provide an example, Layhout?

Comment: like `for (let name of museumNamesForScraping ) { axios.get( ... ).then(res => { ... }).catch(err => {console.log(err.message); console.log("error name", name); continue;})`. if axios fail to get data, catch block will trigger and keyword `continue` will continue the loop to the end. unlike foreach loop, if there's an error in the middle of the loop, foreach will break and stop working.

Comment: If Axios does fail, if I use `continue` will it try the `get` again for the `URL` that failed?

Comment: no. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue